# Strange Jest failures on Travis CI

Tags: reactjs, testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci, jestjs

I'm getting some strange test failures when trying to run my Jest suite via Travis CI. Everything works fine locally.

What's so troubling is that I don't even understand the error. I've attached a screenshot of the output. What I don't understand is that it seems to be running tests from the vendor files, but only on travis and not on my local. In other words, when I run jest on my local machine, I have 64 total test suites, but then on Travis I have 65 test suites. Has anyone run into something like this before or knows about Jest/Travis configuration and can share some insight?

[image: Strange Strangeness]

Comment: Please paste raw travis output instead of screenshot. It will be much easier for us to understand your problem and help you. You can display raw log in travis web interface by clicking on the button in top right corner of job log console (the one you showed us in screenshot).

Comment: I think there is a problem with the way Jest collects your tests. As I can see it collects tests from every file with name enging with `test.js`. Maybe it's because of different version of Jest you have locally and the one installed in travis vm. It is also possible that default `script` command executed in travis. See [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Customizing-the-Build-Step) article to find out how to customize your build steps in `.travis.yml`  Finally you can also try to explicity exclude failing file (... test/cgi/assets/folder/test.js) from your test.

Comment: I think [this](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string) is the way to skip files you don't need to be executed during tests.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. The raw log is enormous. So long that stack overflow won't let me paste it in, which is why I didn't include it. I thought about explicitly excluding the file, but didn't try since the file isn't actually in my repo. I'm going to give it a try anyway and see what happens. I already confirmed that travis is running the same version of Jest as I am on my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forcing Jest to ignore all test files that weren't named `.test` by using the `testRegex` option in the [config](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string)